# How to restart system and desktop after pivot_root

Tags: filesystem, root, reboot, init.d

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 for my OS system.

I had changed to new root with pivot_root.

And tried to restart all the system and the desktop.

I would not try to use reboot cause it will reboot the old root file system instead of the new root filesystem.

How can I do that?

As I know "/sbin/init runlevel" is not available when upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

What else can I do to restart it?

Comment: Perhaps make the one you want to pivot_root to to be an LXC container and run the container?

Comment: @crass I just be curious why package overlayroot can set all this done so perfectly. How to do that?!